# can't access my new class in c# (webb-app)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hello i am learning to program but currently i am stuck.
When i add this class directly in to the file that should be using the class, it works.
When i place this class en in a seperate .cs file, i can't seem to use it.

This is my DAL class for accessing my database (very basic)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DAL
/// </summary>
public class DAL
{

    // We valideren de gegevens die de gebruiker ingeeft met de gegevens in de database.
    public static bool CheckUser(string username, string password)
    {
        DataTable result = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RTIdb"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Wachtwoord FROM Gebruikers Where GebruikersNaam = @uname";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", username));

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        result = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(result);
                    }
                    if (password.Trim() == result.Rows[0]["Wachtwoord"].ToString().Trim())
                    {
                        // Als we hier geraken zijn de ingevoerde gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord correct

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // problem handling
        }
        // gebruikersnaam niet gevonden
        return false;
    }

    public static string GetWeergaveNaam(string username)
    {
        DataTable result = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RTIdb"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT WeergaveNaam FROM Gebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = @uname";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", username));

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        result = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(result);
                    }
                    if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        return result.Rows[0]["WeergaveNaam"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO opvangen exception
        }

        return "SQL ERROR";

    }

    // Nu moeten we de rol van de gebruiker nog opzoeken
    public static string GetUserRoles(string username)
    {
        DataTable result = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RTIdb"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Roles FROM Gebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = @uname";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", username));

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        result = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(result);
                    }
                    if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        return result.Rows[0]["Roles"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception handling
        }
        // user id not found, dus is hij een gast
        return "guest";
    }
}
```

now when i want to access these methods in a different file like

```
DAL.CheckUser(username, password);
```

then i get an error in visual studio saying : "The name 'DAL' does not exist in the current context"
I would assume it hase something todo with namespaces, but i don't have any namespaces declared in any file. Whe i do add the "namespace" declaration, it does not find the namespace in my second file... so in other words i am stuck :-s

I hope someone can send me in the right direction...

Comment: put the `using namespace-name;` then it will be accessible

Comment: A useful shortcut is to place the cursor on `DAL` and hit **[ctrl]** + **[.]**. This will bring up all the options available to you in the current context. One thing I wish I had known when I was starting out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check again about using namespace keyword of your project. I compiled successfully with two classes on two files in two difference folders.

File Business.cs in project folder

```
public class Business
{
    public void TestFunc()
    {
        DAL.TestFunction();
    }
}
```

File DAL.cs in DAL folder

```
public class DAL
{
    public static void TestFunction()
    { 
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class isn't inside a namespace.
To refer to a class that isn't inside a namespace you should use:

```
global::DAL.CheckUser(username, password);
```

Be aware, it's a bad practice not declaring namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for namespacing in here:

1) You can declare both files in the same namespace;

2) You can declare both files in different namespaces and declare a `using` command in the file which needs to refer to the other namespace.

Namespaces group your classes in logical groups. Usually the location of the class in the folder structure of the project is used. Files in 1 namespace can call the protected and public members of each others without a `using` command. Files in different namespaces need to make an explicit `using` reference to the other namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help in clearing the clouds with namespaces. I will follow the folder structure as sugested.